# Au téléphone, comment répondre à quelqu'un qu'on est bien la personne à qui il/elle souhaite parler ?

Tags: téléphone

Si quelqu'un m'appelle au téléphone et demande à parler à « Monsieur [mon nom] », quelle serait la manière la plus élégante de lui communiquer que c'est bien moi, Monsieur [mon nom] ?

Comment: Dans certains contextes, notamment professionnel, l'usage veut qu'on se présente dès qu'on prend l'appel. Ainsi la question ne se pose pas.

Comment: Si la personne ne s'est pas d'abord présentée et que je ne la (re)connais pas, ma première réponse est *C'est de la part ?* Sinon, il m'arrive parfois de répondre *C'est ce que vous faites déjà*.

Answer (score 1):

> C'est moi/moi-même.

Utiliser

> C'est lui/lui-même.
> est [apparemment consideré comme plus formel](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/cest-moi-m%C3%AAme-cest-lui-m%C3%AAme-au-t%C3%A9l%C3%A9phone.2777221/).

Answer (score -1):

To answer to the question

- Je souhaite parler à monsieur Untel

You can answer (if you are monsieur untel)

- Oui, c'est moi.

or a little bit more formally

- Oui, c'est lui-même.

However, answering

- C'est moi-même,
  is both non-sensical and improper. How many times in your life aren't you yourself?

Comment: *Lui-même* tout court me semble encore mieux. PS: Pourquoi avoir répondu en anglais ?

Comment: @jlliagre — Le sens de *lui-même* ou *elle-même* correspond à : « La personne à laquelle vous voulez vous adresser, c'est elle-même qui vous répond ». Garder ses distances est un signe d'élégance aristocratique : Je suis disponible pour vous écouter, (même si vous m'importunez), je vais écouter votre propos (sans vous interrompre), et, quelle que soit ma réponse, je la formulerai pour que vous ne soyez ni offensé, ni familier, puisque nous n'avons pas été déjà présentés.

Comment: @Personne Oui, c'est le sens et la concision de cette réponse qui me fait la préférer.

Comment: Les deux me semblent grammaticalement corrects, dans _c'est moi-même_, _c'_ voulant dire _celui à qui vous souhaitez parler_ et dans _c'est lui-même_, _c'_ voulant dire _celui qui vous parle_. Par contre, ce qui n'est pas clair, c'est pourquoi la deuxième formule est considérée comme plus formelle que la première.

Comment: Une réponse doit témoigner de l'usage réel et pas uniquement de l'opinion de son auteur. "C'est moi-même" est fréquemment utilisé, même si on désapprouve son usage.